# I used this as a code to play a video in android studio but it says "Can't play this video"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I used this as a code to play a video in android studio but it says "Can't play this video". What should i do ?

```
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVideoPath("android.resourse://"+ getPackageName()+ "/" +R.raw.video);
    videoView.start();
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController((mediaController));
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: what is getPackageName() referencing in there may be where your having the issue.

Comment: It refers to the name of the app, which is "VideoDemo" in the above case

Comment: the issue may be in the class videoView

Comment: then what is the solution to it ?

Comment: need to see the code of the videoView

Comment: Why don't you try `ExoPlayer`?